# SELECT * FROM versus SELECT specified FROM

Tags: php, mysql

what will be faster?

`SELECT * FROM`

or

`SELECT specified FROM`

background: table have one field (`specified`) which at the same time is a primary index

Comment: If you care, profile it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your particular case it may very well be the same, but as a matter of good practice, you should always specify the columns you want.

In addition to the various good reasons Dark Falcon put in a comment, it also creates a form of self-documentation in your application code, since it's directly in the query each field you're expecting.

Comment: The reason for this is that when someone inserts a new column in the future, it doesn't break all your existing queries which expected columns to be in a particular order. It also reduces the amount of data selected if you don't need all current and future columns the table may contain.

Comment: @DarkFalcon quite contrary, when you select * , you will select thet freshly added field as well and don't bother with rewriting queries. And depending on the field order is just silly.

Comment: The only good reasons for naming the columns, is to only get the ones you need and for the code to immediately and specifically fall over, if there are changes to the schema.

Answer (score 5):

As a matter of good practice, it's usually better to explicitly specify the columns you want, regardless of the performance implications you're concerned about in this question.

But in general, the answer will depend heavily on your version of `mysql`. Profile it and see:

```
explain select * from ...;
explain select specified from ...;
```

I suspect strongly that this is a case of premature optimization, and that you don't *really* need to know which is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Imho the explicit version will be faster, cause mysql don't need to look up what fields the table contains.

Comment: It has to do a lookup anyway, to verify that the relation exists.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on table structure (including indexes) it may not make a difference -- running some benchmarks and using `EXPLAIN SELECT` to see where things can be improved will help you along the way.  But in general, if you know you only want n fields, only select n fields.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify it, in case in the future more columns are added, but you don't want to retrieve all of them. In any case it is better to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Write a console app with 2 functions doing the two methods and loop 1000 times on each and print out the average time it took. This would be your fastest way to test the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's better and I think faster to specify something in your sql query to avoid to get some unuseful data

Answer (score 0):

The  "select * from" format imho is just a fast way when quering as dba you just want a quick glance at the table.  Even though that will work in programming I wouldn't recommend it, by listing the columns as a programmer it keeps you from having to go back and forth to your db and see what column you want to use or query for.  It keeps you in one spot..that's just me though..this really is up to you and how you want to program.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at this bass ackwards. Do you need the content of the column or not, if you don't and you get it, that will take longer than not.

Parsing the sql to check the column names, order them  and potentially alias them, is trivial compared to flooding the network transferring loads of stuff you don't need.